# Java Auto Clicker not sending to clicks to Minecraft Bedrock Edition Window but sends clicks to every other window and desktop fine

Tags: java, minecraft, awtrobot

I am making a basic auto clicker with one specific goal which is to be able to send mouse inputs to any window and/or application with no error. So far it sends clicks perfectly to any window without error except for Minecraft Bedrock Edition.

This is how I send clicks

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```

I simply create a Robot using the Robot class and then I have the robot press the mouse button down and then up (which is a click). Like I said it works fine for every program except Minecraft Bedrock Edition. I have no idea why I am not able to send mouse inputs to this window as when I use other Java programmed auto clickers such as Vene Clicker or a LGHUB Macro I am able to send mouse inputs without error to any window including Minecraft Bedrock Edition.
(The reason I am making my own basic auto clicker instead of an already working clicker is because I make client side anti cheats for Minecraft so a way for me to learn more about anti cheats is to make basic versions of the cheats I will be detecting for)

Comment: This is one of those "known" kind of issues, where sometimes, the application you're trying to automate can detect events which aren't generated by the hardware and can filter them.  Games are notorious for this - for the very reason that they don't want to support "bots".  It might be possible to do this via different means, but I know, based on gets posted on StackOverflow, that Java `Robot` suffers from this a lot

Comment: @MadProgrammer I thought so, do you know of any ways to send mouse inputs differently with like a different library or separate method from the Robot class? I know it is possible as I have used other auto clickers made in java that can send inputs properly to minecraft bedrock edition.

Comment: So, AFAIK, `Robot` injects events into the native event queue - a little high level, rather then acting at the driver level.  The process may introduce difference which are detectable by some applications.  Without literally dropping to the native level (using JNI/JNA), I doubt you can over come it in Java